# How can I pass a variable from a function to another?

Tags: jquery

I want to pass a variable from one function to another. So I defined the variable `hello` in my first function and then simply want to alert it in my second function:

```
var hello;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

     $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        var hello = table.cell(this).index().columnVisible;
        console.log('Clicked on cell in visible column: ' + hello);
    });

    table.MakeCellsEditable({
        "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
    });
    return hello;
});



function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue,hello) {
    var array = updatedRow.data();
    var id = array[0];
    var hello;
    alert(hello);
    console.log("The new value for the cell is: " + updatedCell.data());
    console.log("The old value for that cell was: " + oldValue);
    console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
    console.log("The id is: " + id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            updatedCell: updatedCell.data(),
            id: id
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

I expect `3`, because in my console I get the output `Clicked on cell in visible column: 3`, but the alert output is `undefined`.

---

UPDATE: Here the solution with only one `var hello`, but the alert is still `undefined`

```
var hello;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

     $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        hello = table.cell(this).index().columnVisible;
        console.log('Clicked on cell in visible column: ' + hello);
    });

    table.MakeCellsEditable({
        "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
    });
    return hello;
});



function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue,hello) {
    var array = updatedRow.data();
    var id = array[0];
    alert(hello);
    console.log("The new value for the cell is: " + updatedCell.data());
    console.log("The old value for that cell was: " + oldValue);
    console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
    console.log("The id is: " + id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            updatedCell: updatedCell.data(),
            id: id
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Just `alert(hello)` in your second function. When you re-declare with `var hello`, you're creating a local instance of the `hello` variable (in other words, a completely different variable). If it's declared in the global context, you don't need to redeclare. Remove all `var hello` from your code, with the exception of the first (global) one and you should be fine.

Comment: @AlejandroIván I removed var hello in my second function, but still the alert output is `undefined`

Comment: There are several `var hello` in your code. There should only be **one** (the global one).

Comment: Please read: https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Comment: @AlejandroIván Thank you very much for the help! I will check it out and post, if I found a solution

Comment: BTW `return hello;` serves no purpose since it is not in a named function. Return is used to pass a value back to where the function was called from. Secondly, even though your issue can be resolved by declaring a global variable it is not good to clutter the global scope.

Comment: @PeterKA Thank you, very difficult case. But I stay on task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the value in a data attribute in the DOM. That way you do have to clutter the global scope. Here's how you can do it.

Store the value in the `table` element:

```
//var hello = table.cell(this).index().columnVisible; <<--- REPLACE WITH
$('#myTable').data( 'hello', table.cell(this).index().columnVisible );
```

Retrieve the value from the table element;

```
 //local variable
 var hello = $('#myTable').data('hello');
```

Another approach would be to define the named function within DOM ready instead of defining it as a global function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hello; //DO NOT redeclare the variable again.
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

     $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
          hello = table.cell(this).index().columnVisible;
          console.log('Clicked on cell in visible column: ' + hello);
     });

      table.MakeCellsEditable({
          "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
      });
      function myCallbackFunction(....) {
          //......REMEMBER DO NOT USE var in front of hello
      }
});
```

Comment: This is working well! I am so happy not to read the word `undefined` in the alert box! Thank you very much. A very interesting solution, what gave you the idea? I would not have think about this

Comment: There are several solution online where the technique has been used. I use it all the time.

Comment: @one last question, I want to use `var hello = $('#myTable').data('hello');alert(hello);` also in the line right above `table.MakeCellsEditable({ "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction});` Why is this not working?

Comment: There it is again undefined

Comment: To retrieve the value you have to have saved before that point. So before invoking `.data('hello')` ensure that you've invoked `.data('hello', value-to-save)` first. If that's not the case, you would do well to post a new question and post the relevant code there.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

remove   `var hello;` from third line in `myCallbackFunction`

Comment: tested it, but still the alert output is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

remove the `var` keyword before "hello" variable from both functions. keep it just in the very first line. If that does not fix the problem, try to remove the parameter `hello` from `myCallbackFunction`;

Comment: But I need to keep it inside the click function, because `hello` defines the number of the column I clicked, isn't that so?

Comment: once you have declared it at the first line, it will be available in all functions (you can use it in all functions). but don't re-declare it with `var` keyword.

Comment: This means inside my click function I change this line `var hello = table.cell(this).index().columnVisible;` to this line `hello = table.cell(this).index().columnVisible;`?

Comment: yes that's it, and also remove `var hello;` from the `myCallbackFunction` function.

Comment: I posted your solution in my question. Unfortunately still `undefined`. I will try to check out what could be the reason and will post it, as soon I have an idea

Comment: @Abedelaziz Mokhnache: If I alert it inside the click function I get the output `3`

Comment: It outputs `Clicked on cell in visible column: 3`

Comment: so sure the problem is in `function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue,hello) ` remove hello from parameters and it will log correctly.